# How do you write the opposite of .classList.contains("class"), meaning classList does not conatin

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how to write the opposite of `this.classList.contains("theClass")` meaning `this.classList.`does not `contains("theClass")`. This is for an if statement. In my case it is

```
if (square.classList.contains("bitCoin")){
        jump();
      }
```

but I want to make it if it DOES NOT contain class `"bitCoin"`.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (!square.classList.contains("bitCoin"))
```